# How do you find methods in the Zend Framework 2 API

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to find utility in the Zend Framework 2 API but can't.  Maybe I'm not using it right.

For example, following the online documentation for Unit Testing in Zend Framework:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/tutorials/unittesting.html

... I see that a class that extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase inherits access to $this->getMockBuilder() from somewhere.  However I cannot find it in the API documentation for the AbstractHttpControllerTestCase class:

http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.3/classes/Zend.Test.PHPUnit.Controller.AbstractHttpControllerTestCase.html

I also don't see a search utility anywhere in the API.  How can one know what methods are available to an extension of this class?  Dig into the code?  Then why publish a partial formal API?

Comment: It's always been the specialty of Zend to not provide full documentation. So maybe you're right that the information you are looking for are not documented.

Comment: Use some advanced IDE with autocomplete, class explorer, and other handy features and you won't have to open any documentation :)

Comment: I agree with @AlexeyKosov, just include ZF2 in your PHP include path, whatever your IDE is.

Comment: I am using Zend Studio 11 and have been fighting with getting code completion to work with anything outside of the current class.  I have ZF2 in my build path.  That will probably be the source for my next SO question :)

Comment: Try PhpStorm, and use /** @var */ declaration for objects from ServiceLocator

Answer (score 0):

That class [extends](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php#L23) phpunit test case to provide additional functionality for controller testing.

For `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` usage refer to [phpunit documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en)

As for how i find methods - i browse code, parent classes and such. Others use their IDE features.